# Permission denied (publickey). heroku git:clone myapp - on Windows

Tags: git, heroku, ssh

I really do a exhaustive search here on Stack and web and not found a solution to this problem.

I just want to clone my repo from heroku git to my work machine, and doing:

```
heroku git:clone myapp
```

or

```
git clone git@heroku.com:myapp.git -o heroku
```

the output is the same for both:

```
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
```

Ok, I have read that this means was not found a ssh public keys on machine.
I added a lot of keys doing from different ways, like:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -f id_rsa
```

or

```
heroku keys:clear
heroku keys:add
```

or

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "my_email[at].com" -f C:\path\.ssh\id_rsa_heroku
```

Can someone explain me what is happening?

There is another way or I missing some step to set up to clone my repo from git successful?

Note: I'm on Windows plataform. Sorry about that :|

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Googling a little more, I found that the git read the ssh keys from a different local of C:\Users\user\.ssh. The git read the ssh keys from C:\Program Files\Git\.ssh

So, copying the generated keys from C:\Users\user\.ssh to C:\Program Files\Git\.ssh and adding theses keys to heroku

```
heroku keys:add
```

it will be able to connecting using ssh.

:)

[Here](http://www.gmarwaha.com/blog/2011/05/18/heroku-trouble-with-windows-and-ssh-keys/) is the real solution.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, but this solution didn't work for me.

Comment: Exactly the same as the original poster of this question.  I suspect it has something to do with where Windows' Git is looking for the keys, but I've already tried putting copies of that in several different locations.  I've given up.  Cygwin's Git works just fine.